# ¿Cómo ingresar solo numeros en un textbox en asp.net?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, textbox

Tengo un asp:textbox y quiero que solo me permita ingresar valores numéricos enteros, no letras ni espacios ni tampoco caracteres. No necesito validar lo que escribo en el textbox despues de enviarlo, sino al momento de escribirlo. He estado intentando hacerlo mediante la propiedad onkeydown algo así:

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="tb_Plazo" runat="server" Class="texto-negro" Width="100%" 
    onkeydown = "return (!(event.keyCode>=65) && event.keyCode!=32)" MaxLength="5"></asp:TextBox>
```

por ahora no me permite ingresar letras ni espacios pero sí algunos caracteres, y yo necesito solo numeros enteros. Si alguien tiene alguna otra idea de poder hacerlo me sería de mucha ayuda.

Comment: Probaste con expresiones regulares?

Comment: @Carlos las expresiones regulares ayudan a validar lo que ingresas cuando lo submiteas, pero no impide hasta donde sé que lo pongas en la caja de texto o no se de que forma sería.

Answer (score 0):

No estás definiendo bien los [**`caracteres ASCII`**](https://elcodigoascii.com.ar/), deberías poner lo siguiente:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tb_Plazo" runat="server" Class="texto-negro" Width="100%" 
    onkeydown = "return (event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57)" MaxLength="5"></asp:TextBox>
```